# perl binding models in /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24/darwin-thread-multi-2level, but directory is empty

Tags: perl

After I installed `JSON.pm` with cpan, perl has started binding the default models to `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24/darwin-thread-multi-2level`  even though the directory is empty.

I receive the following error:

```
perl -e 'use strict;'                    
Can't locate strict.pm:   /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24/darwin-thread-multi-2level/strict.pm: Permission denied at -e line 1.                                           
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

The correct model does exist at `/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.24/strict.pm` and `/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.24` is in the @INC, but after `.../darwin-thread-multi2level`. I have attempted to `port uninstall perl2.24;port install perl2.24`. This has not resolved the issue.

I have attempted `export PERL2LIB=/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.24`, but this does not prevent perl from binding to multi2thread. Is there a way to remove `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24/darwin-thread-multi-2level` from @INC or some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Cpan screwed up the directory/file permissions. Used a script which recursively fixed all the permissions solved the issue.